# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) и возврат к предыдущим активностям

Tags: android-fragment, activity, android-intent

Есть 3 активити, каждая из которых является хостом своего фрагмента.
Фрагмент первого активити запускает второе активити и передаёт её фрагменту интент с данными. Далее со второго фрагмента я запускаю третий активити с фрагментом соответственно.
Далее при переходе с помощью setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) с фрагмента 3 на активити 2, активити 2 начинает заново создавать фрагмент, но интент уже пуст, и он не может найти необходимую информацию.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В каждом из активити сохраняйте его состояние, то есть пришли какие-то параметры (то что вы получаете в интенте) в активити 2, то нужно их запомнить. А это делается так.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("someVarA", someVarA);
    outState.putString("someVarB", someVarB);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    someVarA = savedInstanceState.getInt("someVarA");
    someVarB = savedInstanceState.getString("someVarB");
}
```